# POST all OPTIONS from a select with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to post all my options in a select, so far I only post one value.
What should I add to post all options in my form?

This is the code I got so far

```
    $('.add_button').click(function () {
    $('.valj_grupp_email option:selected').each(function () {
        $("<option/>").
        val($(this).val()).
        text($(this).text()).
        appendTo(".valda_grupper_email");
    //-------------------Here I need help to select all my options in .valda_grupper_email_form-------------------------//  
            $.post(
            'mail_visa_kunder.php',
            $('.valda_grupper_email_form').serialize(),
            function(data){
            $("#testar3").html(data)
            }   
        );
        return false;
    //--------------------------------------------//

    });
});
```

Example of form:

```
<form class="valda_grupper_email_form" method="post">
   <select>
      <option value="1">test1</option>
      <option value="2">test2</option>
      <option value="3">test3</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

I should add that I need to have my html code as it is. Beacuse if I want to delete something from my select list.

Code for the remove:

```
$('.delete_button').click(function () {
    $('.valda_grupper_email option:selected').each(function () {
        $(this).remove();
        $.post(
            'mail_visa_kunder.php',
            $('.valda_grupper_email_form').serialize(),
            function(data){
            $("#testar3").html(data)
            }   
        );
        return false; 
    });
});
```

A pic of my application for you to easier understand.

[image]

Edit:

```
$('.add_button').click(function () {
        var data = '';
        $('#valda_grupper_email option').each(function(){
            data += 'valda_grupper_email=' + $(this).val() + '&';
        });

        $.post(
            'mail_visa_kunder.php',
             data,
             function(data){
                $("#testar3").html(data)
             }   
         );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Edit2: It still only post one value, but now I do not need to select it. Close to a solution :)

```
var emails =  '';
$('.add_button').click(function () {
    $('.valj_grupp_email option:selected').each(function () {
        $("<option/>").
        val($(this).val()).
        text($(this).text()).
        appendTo(".valda_grupper_email");

        $('.valda_grupper_email option').each(function(){
            emails += 'valda_grupper_email=' + $(this).val() + '&';
        });
        $.post(
            'mail_visa_kunder.php',
            emails,
            function(data){
            $("#testar3").html(data)
            }   
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It makes no sense to post _all_ the options in a `select` - it is not a select anymore. Nevertheless, look for the `multiple` attribute, or display an array of `checkbox`es better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to add the `selected` attribute to every select and set the `multiple` attribute on their select:

```
    $("<option/>")
      .val($(this).val())
      .text($(this).text())
      .attr('selected', true)
      .appendTo("#valda_grupper_email");
```

and

```
<form class="valda_grupper_email_form" method="post">
   <select id="valda_grupper_email" name="valda_grupper_email" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">test1</option>
      <option value="2">test2</option>
      <option value="3">test3</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

In the code above I have changed the class 'valda_grupper_email' to an ID, since I assume the select is unique, and unique elements are best targeted using IDs.

If you would rather not change the markup but only the way the ajax call is made, you could do it like this:

```
var emails =  '';
$('#valda_grupper_email option').each(function(){
    emails += 'valda_grupper_email[]=' + $(this).val() + '&';
});

$.post(
    'mail_visa_kunder.php',
     emails,
     function(data){
        $("#testar3").html(data)
     }   
 );
```

Comment: There is one problem with that for me. I have the option to remove a option in the select list. So I need to post all options without changing the html code.

Comment: My answer now includes such a solution as well.

Comment: I feel like a retard now, but my skills in javascript/jQuery is very limited.

Tried to apply your code like this:

`$('.add_button').click(function () {
   var data = '';
   $('#valda_grupper_email option').each(function(){
    data += 'valda_grupper_email=' + $(this).val() + '&';
   });

   $.post(
    'mail_visa_kunder.php',
     data,
     function(data){
     $("#testar3").html(data)
     }   
    );
   return false;
  });
 });`

Now none of my scripts work, and I cant see the problem :S

Sorry for the caos in the code, I put the same code in my post at the bottom.

Comment: Did you also add the id 'valda_grupper_email' to the select? My second alternative still assumes that change of your markup. You can otherwise replace "#valda_grupper email" with ".valda_grupper_email_form select" everywhere. I also updated my answer since the choice of 'data' as the variable to hold the option values was pretty stupid. I can't spot any problems with how you implemented my answer in your code otherwise...

Comment: Yes I added that to. But when I implement your code none of my jQuery code will run. Do not know why, and when I change back to the original everything works again.

Comment: I see now that there are too many closing parenthesis: `$('.add_button').click(function () { ... }); });`. Remove the final `});` and things might work better.

Comment: I still only post one option value to my php file. Did like this and also post the code in OP:
`var emails =  '';
 $('.add_button').click(function () {
  $('.valj_grupp_email option:selected').each(function () {
   $("<option/>").
   val($(this).val()).
   text($(this).text()).
   appendTo(".valda_grupper_email");
   
   $('.valda_grupper_email option').each(function(){
    emails += 'valda_grupper_email=' + $(this).val() + '&';
   });
   $.post(
    'mail_visa_kunder.php',
    emails,
    function(data){
    $("#testar3").html(data)
    } 
   );
   return false;
  });
 });`

Comment: It is possible that PHP is so stupid that you have to call your POST parameter "valda_grupper_email[]" instead, to make it realize you are passing multiple values for a single parameter. I'll update my answer in a second.

Comment: Glad I could help in the end!

Answer (score 0):

## [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/6QMKn/)

```
var all_options = [];

$("#valda_grupper_email option").each(function()
{
    all_options.push(this.value);
});

var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(all_options);
```

now you can send json string in your jquery `POST`

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to implement this with my post.